# take time and append to date to make datetime?

Tags: c#, datetime

Say I have the following:

```
string fromTime = "8:00am";
string someDate = "06/01/2012";
```

I want to end up doing this:

```
DateTime dt = Convert.ToDateTime(someDate + someTime);
```

Basically I want to take a date and add the time to it with the result for the above to be

`06/01/2012 8:00am`

But have it stored in a datetime variable.  Is this possible?

Comment: Tricky part is making it work on different cultures with different date/time settings. For example "06/01/2012" means January 6th in USA but it means June 1st in England. See the problem in your approach?

Comment: Not griping or anything, just curious, why are you storing these in strings?

Comment: @ShadowWizard this app will only work in the US.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use [the DateTime.TryParseExact](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.tryparseexact.aspx) method which allows you to specify a format when parsing:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        string s = "06/01/2012 8:00am";
        string format = "dd/MM/yyyy h:mmtt";
        DateTime date;
        if (DateTime.TryParseExact(s, format, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out date))
        {
            Console.WriteLine(date);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you give an example of how to use this?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
DateTime dt = DateTime.ParseExact(someDate + " " + someTime, "MM/dd/yyyy h:mmtt", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```